# add integers from SQL column in php

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help with a query?

I have a php page that I want to assign a number to a variable, I want the number to be integers added together from a mySQL database. In this example, the numbers are in the "assigndatx" column, my query looks like this:

```
$AssignDates = mysql_query("select assigndatx from opencall where status < 2")
```

(opencall is the table, I'm only wanting those with status of 0 or 1). Can anyone help me with the code to add all the results together?

Comment: Why do it in PHP when you could do it in SQL?

Comment: `SUM()` function maybe?

Comment: Is "adding together" the same as `SUM(assigndatx)`?

Comment: Why `mysql_query`? Legacy application?

Comment: Did you give up on this one???

Answer (score 6):

```
$AssignDates = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(assigndatx) as total FROM opencall WHERE status < 2")

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssignDates);
$total  = $result['total'];
```

Also, I should add that you need to move away from `mysql_` funcs and use `mysqli`_ or `PDO`.

Comment: This is indeed the right way to do it, but the OP hasn't answered why he wants to do it in PHP and not MySQL. So it may not actually answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssignDates)  {
$sum += $row['assigndatx'];
}
return $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switched to mysqli, you could do:

```
$result= mysqli_query("select assigndatx from opencall where status < 2");
$rows= mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo array_sum($rows);
```

my personal preference would be to use

```
select sum(assigndatx) as total from opencall where status < 2
```

for the SQL and avoid doing it at all in php.

Comment: I don't understand the personal preference statement. If he needs to use the data in a PHP script, he has to get any data from the MySQL result set into PHP by using mysql/mysqli/PDO extensions.

Comment: Of course I'm assuming that it's the only thing that was needed.